# Reading large data file 4 GB in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, large-files

I'm having a problem reading a 3.8 GB file using fstream ? 
there should be another way of reading it. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the problem? Errors/Logs?

Comment: @Matt: Probably the fact that sizes and offsets are usually 32 bits.

Comment: @Mehrdad that 32 bit should be able to represent 4 billion addresses (if unsigned).

Comment: `fstream` is usually able to handle files larger than `std::streamoff` and related types, though I'm not sure what the standard requires.

Comment: @H2CO3, you don't usually get use of the full 32 bits of address space. Windows 32 bit for example gives you a maximum of [3GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx), and I suspect Linux is similar.

Comment: @H2CO3: 4 billion is 4gb... isn't that the problem?

Comment: @Mehrdad no. If 4 billion corresponds to 4GB, then in theory it would be possible to represent a 4GB file on 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You can't read a file that large all at once on a 32 bit operating system. You need a 64 bit operating system and a 64 bit compiler.

Better yet would be to break the problem down so that you don't have to read the whole file at once.

Comment: If I recall, Visual Studio's default streams doesn't work quite right on files over 2GB in 32bit builds, so even if he breaks the problem down that might not be enough.

Comment: I haven't encountered any problems using `fstream` to handle files larger than 4 GB on Visual Studio 2005 and up.

Comment: @dauphic: the problem is only observed if you use seek/tell for the most part.  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/627639 says it even applied to the x64 versions until VC11.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned, I think you need a 64 bit OS to read a file this big.

Also, assuming you are trying to read this file from a disk, you should implement some kind of buffer to attenuate the effects of the slow speed. This potentially will fix your problem (depending on the implementation). If you posted more information on the problem we may be able to help you more specifically.

Here is an example of what you may use:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/